# Calculating Prize Line Expectation Part 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Thanks in advance for any help.

Yesterday a very helpful member called @joriki answered my original question on this and that conversation came to a conclusion as a result. I have a second part that extends the problem a little.

This was the original post: [Calculating Expected Increase In Prize Line Count](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662689/calculating-expected-increase-in-prize-line-count/4662697#4662697)

To summarise, the base problem of calculating the expected increase in prize lines from one turn using only number pools containing numbers was I think solved but I was having difficulty when introducing wildcard symbols. What joriki was finally able to get through to me was that using my proposed solution I was overcounting the probability boost of the wildcard symbols because I was applying them to multiple incomplete lines originating from a particular cell and that in reality that wildcard would only be able to apply to one or the other number in the target column and therefore only one incomplete prize line containing the originating cell number. By making a pseudo choice of target prize line in my line calculations, the calculated probability matched my brute forced probability. So far so good again.

I went on in my investigation to increase the number of wildcards in the same column. My reasoning was that I would not be able to apply those wildcards to more incomplete lines but that the probability of achieving those lines to which it is applied would be increased because of the increased ratio of wildcards to numbers. Here are my workings:

```
[1] [x] [7] 
[2] [x] [8] 
[3] [x] [9] 

Number pools: 
 1   4   7 
 2   5   8 
 3   6   9 
         *
         *
```

This time the brute forced combinations and prize line increases are as follows. There are now 45 (3x3x5) possible draw combinations.

```
147(1),148(0),149(1),14*(1),14*(1),157(1),158(0),159(1),15*(1),15*(1),167(1),168(0),169(1),16*(1),16*(1)
247(0),248(1),249(0),24*(1),24*(1),257(0),258(1),259(0),25*(1),25*(1),267(0),268(1),269(0),26*(1),26*(1)
347(1),348(0),349(1),34*(1),34*(1),357(1),358(0),359(1),35*(1),35*(1),367(1),368(0),369(1),36*(1),36*(1)
```

33 additional prize lines / 45 draw combinations = 0.73333 expected increase in complete prize lines. This time we apply our solution in the same way as when there was only 1 wildcard on the draw but increase the probability boost for the boosted lines to reflect the ratio of wildcards to numbers in the pool.

```
Line 1->4->7 = ⅓ * ⅗ = 0.20000
Line 2->5->8 = ⅓ * ⅗ = 0.20000
Line 3->6->9 = ⅓ * ⅗ = 0.20000
Line 1->2->3 = 0 (not possible to complete this line in a single draw) 
Line 7->8->9 = 0 (not possible to complete this line in a single draw) 
Line 1->5->9 = ⅓ * ⅕ = 0.06666
Line 3->5->7 = ⅓ * ⅕ = 0.06666
```

The sum of these probabilities is 0.73332 which ~= 0.73333. Again if we boost the precision we’re going to be very close indeed.

Again, so far so good. So then I decided to move a step further and add wildcard symbols to multiple number pools. Below you can see I've added a wildcard to column 1's number pool and left one in column 3's number pool. This time I've changed the board configuration so only 2 numbers are checked off in advance. Here are my workings:

```
[1] [4] [7] 
[2] [x] [8] 
[3] [x] [9] 

Number pools: 
 1   4   7 
 2   5   8 
 3   6   9 
 *       *
```

This time we have 48 (4x3x4) possible number pool combinations to brute force. (Using W instead of * as it isn't translated well by the editor)

147(2),148(1),149(2),14W(2),157(0),158(0),159(1),15W(1),167(0),168(0),169(1),16W(1)
247(1),248(2),249(1),24W(2),257(0),258(1),259(0),25W(1),267(0),268(1),269(0),26W(1)
347(2),348(1),349(2),34W(2),357(1),358(0),359(1),35W(1),367(1),368(0),369(1),36W(1)
W47(2),W48(2),W49(2),W4W(2),W57(1),W58(1),W59(1),W5W(1),W67(1),W68(1),W69(1),W6W(1)

50 additional prize lines completed / 48 number pool combinations = 1.04167 expected additional lines completed by a single draw. Now we apply our proposed solution:

```
Line 1->4->7 = ½ * ⅓ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.33333 * 0.5 = 0.08333 //both wildcards used to boost 1 + 7
Line 2->5->8 = ½ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 //both wildcards used to boost 2 + 8
Line 3->6->9 = ½ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 //both wildcards used to boost 3 + 9
Line 1->2->3 = 0
Line 4->5->6 = ⅓ = 0.33333
Line 7->8->9 = 0
Line 1->5->9 = ¼ * ¼ = 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.0625
Line 3->5->7 = ¼ * ¼ = 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.0625
```

The sum of these probabilities = 1.04166 ~= 1.04167. Again more precision will get these numbers very close together indeed.

So once again, things look to be so far so good. However, if I experiment moving the wildcard probability boost around to different incomplete lines, I get diverging values once again. See my workings here (assuming the same board state and number pools as in the above example):

```
Line 1->4->7 = ¼ * ⅓ * ¼ = 0.25*0.33333*0.25 = 0.02083
Line 2->5->8 = ½ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 //both 2 + 8 boosted
Line 3->6->9 = ¼ * ¼ = 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.0625
Line 1->2->3 = 0
Line 4->5->6 = ⅓ = 0.33333
Line 7->8->9 = 0
Line 1->5->9 = ½ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 //both 1 + 9 boosted
Line 3->5->7 = ½ * ½ = 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25 //both 3 + 7 boosted
```

The above probabilities summed up give me 1.11041, which is way above my brute force calculation. I am hoping that this is because there is a rule for how wildcard probabilities must be applied that I am overlooking in my ignorance.

To be clear on how I'm adding the probability boost that a wildcard adds: If a number in pool 3 has a 1/4 chance of being drawn (1 instance of the number in the pool, 4 numbers and or wildcards in total), when I apply the wildcard to that incomplete prize line, I am boosting the probability of matching that number to 1/2 (1 instance of the number, 1 instance of the wildcard that I wish to use, 4 numbers and or wildcards in total). I am doing this in the same way for both columns when the boosts are applied.

I've also tried balancing out the probability boost across all numbers and also splitting the wildcards amongst incomplete lines according to the rule of not having boosted the probability for that number in any other incomplete prize line calculation but these methods also give me values that are varying degrees of divergence from the brute forced value.

I think I'm making an incorrect assumption somewhere or not applying the correct rule to placement of these wildcards somewhere that's causing my problem but I'm not sure what else to try.

Many thanks in advance for your time and any help!

Answer (score 1):

You’re again making multiple use of combinations. The draw `J5J` is rightly only counted once in `J5J(1)`, but the probabilities for the lines $258$, $159$ and $357$ all assume that you’d use a draw of `J5J` in those lines. Perhaps it would help to note down in the first listing how you’re using the wildcards, e.g. `J[2]5J[8](1)` where you have `J5J(1)`; that might make it easier to only count them once in the other approach. You have to think about where you can use them in order to deduce the `(1)`, anyway, so you might as well write it down, since it somehow seems to be less confusing for you in that context than in the other one.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes!->easier for the examples to note it down so I will do. What I'm trying to achieve of course is a method of calculating these lines without having done the brute force part first so I need to know how to do those calculations without that help. Is the layman's reason why example 1 works and example 2 does not because example 1 does not repeat ANY of the numbers across incomplete lines that have boosted probability? I.e. when creating these line equations, I must not assign a wildcard to any containing a number already occurring in a previous wildcard line calculation?

Comment: Summarising that question :) If I take any given board state and have no access to previously brute forced number combinations but I know the contents of the number pools, how do I easily know where to assign increased probability as a result of wildcards to attain the correct expected value (that would match a brute forced calculation)?

Comment: @DaisyDay: It's not that you have to **know** where to assign it, you have to **decide** where to assign it. You can only use each wildcard as one particular number. If you were hoping to use the second approach with the lines in order to not have to think about what you do with each particular combination: That's not going to work. The two approaches are just two different ways of organizing what's essentially the same sum, and in both you need to fix for each drawn combination what the wildcards are used for.

Comment: @DaisyDay: By the way, there's also the option of assigning half the probability to one line and half to the other. That would allow you to avoid these choices that may seem arbitrary. But I think that's going to become rather confusing once you get to cases where a wildcard can be used to complete one line in one place or two lines in another. To my mind, the easiest way to have a clean bookkeeping of what probability is being taken into account where is to decide how you're going to use the wildcards in each case.

Comment: Thanks. Ok the line 'You can only use each wildcard as one particular number' is a very useful fact to know. I'm very happy to make a choice in my calculations and only increase the probability of 1 particular number in 1 particular incomplete line calculation. That makes me ask why the first multi-wildcard example is not wrong though because I'm boosting the probability for all of 1,2 and 3 and all of 7,8 and 9 (albeit in completely separate incomplete lines) and I'm getting the exact predicted value. Also I did try spreading the probability across multiple lines but ran into similar issues.

Comment: I guess what I'm really saying is that it's absolutely fine for me to choose the the lines to apply the wildcards to (i'm not trying to avoid that) but I need a rule to follow which stops me from (i'll be running this in an application's business logic) misusing/reusing them in my calculations. To me it looks like I've only applied them to 123 and 789 in either column and in separate lines but clearly the first one is right and the second is wrong. I can only see that I've chosen lines in ex 2 that go through the pre-checked off '5'. 3-6-9 line could equally be checked off by drawing J5J.

Comment: The middle pool draw does not have to contain the number the incomplete line we're completing bisects so I'm not assuming J5J is only being used to complete those which do bisect 5 because 5 is already checked off so it's not necessary.

Comment: @DaisyDay: I'm sorry, I'm finding it really hard to follow you. I don't understand the analogy that you're drawing between the correct example and the incorrect example. Perhaps you can say more specifically where exactly you think you're doing the same potentially wrong thing in the correct example as in the incorrect example? I can't identify any point in the correct example where you're using a particular wildcard in a particular combination for more than one number. Please be as specific as possible if you think you are. Which wildcard in which combination are you double-counting there?

Comment: I'm really sorry - I know how frustrating it is when someone's just not getting it. What I need is to be able to reliably perform the second method of calculation against any board and any number pools, with a proven rule for selecting the places in which to assign the wildcard probability. I know they can go in multiple potential places and that's fine; I just need to know how to avoid putting them in the incorrect places. If you could ELI5 in reliable steps I'd be so grateful! A colleague, who is much better with maths than me, also can't figure it out so I don't feel quite as dim :) Sorry!

Comment: n.b. I must be able to do this in isolation without any brute forcing of number combinations etc.

Comment: @DaisyDay: We can't go on like this in the comments; that's not what they're for, and we don't seem to be making much progress in understanding each other. Let's try to find a time when we're both available for a chat.

Comment: Thanks that would be so useful. I'm around all afternoon or anytime tomorrow. I'm on UK time btw..

Comment: I have you the bounty anyway but would still be keen to resolve